# CSS combining % and px width

Tags: html, css

I've a div with width in percentage. Is it possible to align two divs inside it (on left and right) so that the left div has fixed width defined in the px and margin to right in percentage, while the rest of width goes to the right div.

For example consider this:

```
<div class="box"> 

    <div class="left">

    </div>

    <div class="right">

    </div>
</div>

.box{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}


.left{
    float:left;
    margin-right:5%;
    width:100px;    
}


.right{
    Problem..
}
```

Here's jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/s8Gwb/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't mix relative and absolute values, since it's hard or even impossible to calculate correct margins or position values with CSS only.

[`calc()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc0) hasn't been implemented in any browser and is *"at-risk and may be dropped during the CR period"*.

If you still want to achieve something like this you should consider the following:

```
<div class="box">   
    <div class="left">left content</div>   
    <div class="right-wrapper">    
        <div class="right">right content</div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

```css
.left{
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
}
.right-wrapper{
    margin-left:100px;
}
.right{
    margin-left: 5%;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5hKvj/)

Answer (score 2):

```
.box{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow:hidden;
}


 .left{
    float:left;
    margin-right:5%;
     width:100px;

 }


.right{
    float:right;
   left:100px;    //notice this same as width of div left
    position:absolute;
```

}
  Hope this works for you.

Comment: @Zoltan Toth That is already resolved, see this one: http://jsfiddle.net/s8Gwb/28/

Answer (score 2):

Please see if this is the effect you want: http://jsfiddle.net/s8Gwb/28/

I have edited your css and removed float: right from the .right layer

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps abandon this idea, use an absolute positioned div with a floating div that has a margin. This what you want?
http://jsfiddle.net/jefffabiny/s8Gwb/39/